# How do you set default_url_options in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How do you set default_url_options in Rails 4? 
The [apidocs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/default_url_options) says the method is deprecated since 2.3.8. I know i can put

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { ... }
```

inside env files but how can I overide it for certain controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

Just add a private method default_url_options to the controllers.